# Upload files from SharePoint to another website

Tags: sharepoint-server, file

I'm looking for a solution to upload files directly from SharePoint to another website. In my work, I need to upload reports that are stored in SharePoint to a state agency website.  It asks for you to upload a document from your computer, but since SharePoint is a website it is not searchable when taking this type of action.

I need a solution where I can browse the document libraries on SharePoint and find one or multiple files I need to upload to the state agency's website.  What I have to do now is save the file on my computer to have it accessible for the uploading process.  This is an inefficient process.

So, does anyone know of any third party solution or has anyone been facing these issues?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for a way to modify the file dialog when browsing SharePoint libraries. You can use the Common File dialog in SharePoint and create a Custom Web View to update the UI as you would like to.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh967656(v=office.14).aspx) details the steps involved in updating the custom webview.